# dynamically open a inputbox in excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have a excel table and a specific area. This area can be
*Range("A1:A5")* for example and *only has to accept* 0 and 1. And it has to open a Inputbox *automatically* when the user enters a 0 (only clicking on a button or something like that). Of course in that moment.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address.Value = 0 Then 'open InputBox
End If
End Sub`

Have this but this does not work.

Thanks all.

Comment: This is not a site where you tell what you want and anyone does the work for you. People are here to help you to improve something yourself, that you already tried (and maybe is not working well).

Comment: I know that. Who says I did nothing? And I don't want that anyone does the work for me I am only searching for tips. thank you @Peh

Comment: But your "question" (you didn't even ask one) sounds exactly like that if you don't show what you already did/tried. Nevermind, read [ask] and post your code (at least an [mcve]) that you already tried. If you don't ask a **specific** question to code or something it will shortly be declared as off-topic and too broad by the community.

Comment: ok. I'm sorry. Will not happen again @Peh

Comment: Nevermind, you can just [edit] your question and add the missing parts to improve your question. Good questions are just more likely to be answered.

Comment: What you want to do with input box?

Comment: I want to write the value of the Inputbox into another table. This is my result till now. `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim valueEnter As Variant
        
    If Target.Value = 0 Then
        valueEnter = InputBox("Gebe die ein:", "Eingabe")
        If valueEnter = False Then 'if its empty
        Exit Sub
        'write it into the other table
    End If
End Sub
` @Mrig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim valueEnter As Long, lastRow As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:A5") 'specify your range here
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Or Target.Value <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    valueEnter = InputBox("Gebe die ein:", "Eingabe")
    If valueEnter >= 0 Then
        Range("B" & lastRow + 1) = valueEnter
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:___________________________________________________________**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim valueEnter As Variant, lastRow As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:A5") 'specify your range here
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Or Target.Value <> 0 Then GoTo Jump
    valueEnter = InputBox("Gebe die ein:", "Eingabe", 1)
    If IsNumeric(valueEnter) Then
        If valueEnter > 0 Then
            Range("B" & lastRow + 1) = CInt(valueEnter)
            Target.Value = ""
        End If
    Else
        Target.Value = ""
    End If
Jump:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @flowers1234 - Give details on `write the value of the Inputbox into another table`.

Comment: the code for the Inputbox belongs to table 1. And I want to take the value of the Inputbox into another range in the table2 in my workbook. (only write the value of Inputbox into the table2 in range B1,B2,B3, always in the next which is empty =) @Mrig

Comment: @flowers1234 - So value of input box should be entered in `B1`,if not empty then in `B2`, if not empty then in `B3`, and so on?

Comment: Yes exactly! I think it should be something like that `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @flowers1234 - That's up to you.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much ! @Mrig

Comment: @flowers1234 - I've added another code. This will be more stable handling escape or cancel press for input box, removing 0 from the range when entered.

Comment: thx! but what I noticed now. That it started to write from cell B10 or something like that not from the first cell of Range B :/ i m confused :D

Comment: @flowers1234 - Still having prebolem?